# How to run rds sql seed script in cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

i'm trying to rewrite my infrastructure to cdk, I want to create ECS cluster with rails app with RDS MySQL, but I don't want to allow rails to connect with admin credentials, so I need to create rails user in db with proper GRANTS, how can I add mysql user with credentials from SSM with specific GRANTS?

Comment: Use a custom resource that connects to RDS and sets up the credentials.